# TextView not showing up in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to dynamically build a View from Java, and I am confused why this isn't working.

The TextView `displayText` does not show up on the screen at all. I don't see why it wouldn't as its above where the user enters their name.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout ceriLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        Button genButton = new Button(this);
        genButton.setText("Press here");
        genButton.setId(0);

        TextView displayView = new TextView(this);
        displayView.setText("What is going to go here huh");
        displayView.setId(1);

        EditText nameView = new EditText(this);
        nameView.setText("Enter your name");
        nameView.setId(2);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams button = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams name = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams display;
        display = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        button.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        button.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        display.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        display.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, nameView.getId());

        name.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        name.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, genButton.getId());



        ceriLayout.addView(genButton, button);
        ceriLayout.addView(nameView,name);

        setContentView(ceriLayout);

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, slow down man. Are you designing your entire layout on code? Did you know you can use xml files as layouts?

Comment: `ceriLayout.addView(displayView...`? Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding `displayView` into your `ceriLayout`. That's why it does not show up.

**An advice:** Please try to learn writing your `View` components inside `.xml` layout files and set those layouts as content views of activities.